# How can I do batch insert using ibatis annotations

Tags: java, jdbc, ibatis.net

I cannot find a tutorial on this, and I find the documentation scant.  How can I do batch insert using ibatis annotations?

```
public interface MyTableMapper {
    @Insert("insert into MyTable(col1) values (#{valueOfCol1})")
    void insert(MyRecordClass obj);
}


public class MyTransactionalClass {
    @Transactional
    public void insert(MyRecordClass obj) {
        myTableMapperInst.insert(obj);
    }
}
```

I did this naive implementation (surprisingly without success :-):

```
public class MyTransactionalClass {
@Transactional(executorType = ExecutorType.BATCH)       
 public void insert(MyRecordClass obj) {
        myTableMapperInst.insert(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is without annotation, according to the docs, your way seems correct.

```
try {
    sqlMap.startTransaction()
    List list = (Employee) sqlMap.queryForList("getFiredEmployees", null);
    sqlMap.startBatch ();
    for (int i=0, n=list.size(); i < n; i++) {
        sqlMap.delete ("deleteEmployee", list.get(i));
    }
    sqlMap.executeBatch();
    sqlMap.commitTransaction();
    } finally {
        sqlMap.endTransaction();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

iBatis annotation insert bulk record you can do like this

```
 @Insert({"<script>", 
        "insert into  user_master (first_name,last_name) values ",
        "<foreach collection='userList' item='user' index='index' open='(' separator = '),(' close=')' >#{user.first_name},#{user.last_name}</foreach>",
        "</script>"})
    int insertUserList(@Param("userList") List<UserNew> userList);
```

It's work for me and i inserted bulk record in my PostgreSQL database using above single insert.